# tidytext example filter error with pipes

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, tidytext

When trying to reproduce the example found in http://tidytextmining.com/twitter.html there's a problem.

Basically I want to adapt this part of the code

```
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)

reg <- "([^A-Za-z_\\d#@']|'(?![A-Za-z_\\d#@]))"

tidy_tweets <- tweets %>% 
    mutate(text = str_replace_all(text, "https://t.co/[A-Za-z\\d]+|http://[A-Za-z\\d]+|&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|RT", "")) %>%
    unnest_tokens(word, text, token = "regex", pattern = reg) %>%
    filter(!word %in% stop_words$word,
        str_detect(word, "[a-z]"))
```

in order to keep the stop_Word included dataframe of tweets.

So i tried this :

```
tidy_tweets <- tweets %>% 
    mutate(text = str_replace_all(text, "https://t.co/[A-Za-z\\d]+|http://[A-Za-z\\d]+|&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|RT", "")) %>%
    unnest_tokens(word, text, token = "regex", pattern = reg) 

tidy_tweets_sw <- filter(!word %in% stop_words$word, str_detect(tidy_tweets, "[a-z]"))
```

But that did not work as i got the following error message :

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) :  
'match' requires vector arguments
```

I have tried to pass a vector version of both inputs to match, but to no avail. 
Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: tidytext usually uses `anti_join(stop_words)` in the vignettes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure but I think your problem is here:

```
tidy_tweets_sw <- filter(!word %in% stop_words$word, str_detect(tidy_tweets, "[a-z]"))
```

`filter` has no clue about what you want to filter at all, this should work:

```
tidy_tweets_sw <- tidy_tweets %>% filter(!word %in% stop_words$word, str_detect(tidy_tweets, "[a-z]"))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot ("I should have known")!

Comment: Well, that's the problem with piping I think, it's easy to forget the most left arg is the first to any function  on the right :)

Comment: The `tweets` should be changed to `tidy_tweets` to reflect Oki's intermediate step

Comment: Good catch @JakeKaupp didn't think about it, I was focused on the missing pipe :).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the data in your `filter` statement as your first argument.

```
tidy_tweets <- tweets %>% 
  mutate(text = str_replace_all(text, "https://t.co/[A-Za-z\\d]+|http://[A-Za-z\\d]+|&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|RT", "")) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text, token = "regex", pattern = reg) 

tidy_tweets_sw <- filter(tidy_tweets, !(word %in% stop_words$word), str_detect(tidy_tweets, "[a-z]"))
```